# How do I prevent downloadHandler from prompting user for save location? I want it to automatically save to a specified location without prompting

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have written a shiny application that allows users to produce and download html rmarkdown reports. This works.

However, when the report is generated, the user is prompted for a save location. I can certainly include a location in the filename, but the user is still prompted.

Ideally, I would like the user to click the download button and have the file automatically sent to a specific location.

Here is a sample app that works:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sliderInput("slider", "Slider", 1, 100, 50),
    downloadButton("report", "Generate report"),
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$report <- downloadHandler(
      # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
      filename = paste("My name", ".html", sep=""),
      content = function(file) {
        # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
        # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir 
        tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
        file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

        # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
        params <- list(n = input$slider)

        # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
        # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
        # from the code in this app).
        rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                          params = params,
                          envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
        )
      }
    )
  }
)
```

and an rmarkdown script:

````
---
title: "Dynamic report"
output: html_document
params:
  n: NA
---

  ```{r}
# The `params` object is available in the document.
params$n
```

A plot of `params$n` random points.

```{r}
plot(rnorm(params$n), rnorm(params$n))
```
````

Comment: You interact with shiny applications via a web browser. It would be a security risk if web browsers allows websites just to save whatever files they wanted to on a user's computer without interaction. This just isn't allowed. You'd have to write your own custom web browser to enable this type of behavior.

Comment: Interesting. Is there any way to get download handler to send files any other way? Like through email?

Comment: @MrFlick interesting solution, writing your own browser, never thought of that one :) Pete - yes you can send email through shiny, a google search will likely point you to many stackoverflow threads that show different ways to do that